# How can I tell my Dockerfile what DNS to use in RUN commands from docker-compose?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, dockerfile

Say I have a docker compose file like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  randomDNStest:
    dns: 
      - ###.###.###.###
    network_mode: "host"
    build: .
```

and a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner

RUN ["gitlab-runner", "register", "--non-interactive", "--url", "THE INTERNAL GIT LAB INSTANCE", "--registration-token", "MY TOKEN", "--executor", "docker", "--tag-list", "docker", "--description", "DESCRIPTION", "--docker-image",  "docker:19.03.1", "--docker-dns", "###.###.###.###",  "--docker-privileged", "--docker-tlsverify", "--docker-volumes", "/certs/client"]
```

How can I specify the DNS server for the Dockerfile to use at build time (in the run command)?

### Things similar to what I want but not right:

- Using `docker run --dns`.

  - Doesn't work with docker-compose.
- Modifying the DNS service on the host to listen on a non-localhost address that is reachable from within the container as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) and implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400886/docker-cannot-resolve-dns-on-private-network).

  - Probably works, but requires set-up on the host.
- Using the `dns` section in docker-compose as shown above.

  - This works at run-time, not build-time.
- Using curl's `--dns-servers` parameter with the parameters described [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3553)

  - Curl command format: `curl -X POST -F token=QytSH_88wASA_LA6G2mf --dns-servers ###.###.###.### https://INTERNAL_GIT_LAB//api/v4/runners`
  - Curl's `--dns-servers` command must be compiled in as described [in the curl docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) and [in Nathan Leclaire's blog](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2016/08/11/curl-with-http2-support---a-minimal-alpine-based-docker-image/), but I couldn't get the dependencies right, and this only avoids using the problem for my specific use case.
- Using the `network_mode: "host"` driver as shown above and described [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

  - This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to run this command in your `Dockerfile`.  The basic concept there is that you can `docker build` an image once, and then `docker run` multiple copies of that container, or push the image to a registry and run it from other systems.  A GitLab runner image that once upon a time has been registered with some particular server isn't especially useful to re-`docker run` later on.

The [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) for this image suggests it isn't intended to be used as a base image at all.  You can just put the command and other settings in your `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2'
services:
  randomDNStest:
    dns: 
      - ###.###.###.###
    command: >-
      register
      --non-interactive
      --url THE_INTERNAL_GITLAB_INSTANCE
      ...
```

(If this returns immediately, re-running `docker-compose up` will repeat the command.)

Comment: When I do this, I get `gitlab-runner    | Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=` ...
`gitlab-runner    | Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!`
`gitlab-runner exited with code 0`

Comment: Registration does work, but the runner isn't started

Comment: Oh, I need to add `gitlab-runner run`... doh

Comment: Wait,  actually I can only run one command, so I can't use `run` after registering

Comment: Ok, it looks like I can just add another container for a second command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands#30064175