# Local gitlab pipeline error during connect

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a local Gitlab setup and trying to build a pipeline that runs a SAST scan using MobSF. Upon trying to pull the image of MobSF in order to run it I get the following error:

```
error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=opensecurity%2Fmobile-security-framework-mobsf&tag=latest: dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

The error comes up on any script line referencing a Docker command.

**The whole output of the pipeline is:**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.0.0 (3b6f852e)
on pipeline 5qvFbM4s
Preparing the "docker" executor 00:04
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on runner-5qvfbm4s-project-2-concurrent-0 via TheOneWhoKnocks...
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/root/sast-dast-security-testing/.git/
Checking out e71038e1 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Using docker image sha256:25a1e57c774167d28c44d88fa296f3e1122c6d79e99b98653c899b170393bbd6 for docker:18.09.7-dind with digest docker@sha256:a490c83561c1cef49b6fe12aba2c31f908391ec3efe4eb173225809c981e50c3 ...
$ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375
$ docker pull opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf
Using default tag: latest
error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=opensecurity%2Fmobile-security-framework-mobsf&tag=latest: dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This is my **.gitlab-ci.yaml**:

```
stages:
  - build
  - mobsf


build:
  image: docker:18.09.7-dind
  stage: build
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""    
  script:
    - docker pull opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf
    - docker run -i --env-file ./env.list -p 8000:8000 opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest


mobsf:
  image: owasp/glue:raw-latest
  stage: mobsf
  script:
    - ./scan.sh
    - docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app owasp/glue:raw-latest ruby bin/glue -t Dynamic -T /app/report.json --mapping-file mobsf --finding-file-path /app/android.json -z 2
```

And this is my runner's **config.toml**:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "pipeline"
  url = "http://192.168.179.129/"
  token = "XXXXX"
  executor = "docker"      
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly obvious that Google's public DNS servers won't resolve your local DNS requests. "docker"

> error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=opensecurity%2Fmobile-security-framework-mobsf&tag=latest: dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host

Try this answer, i was facing similar one when registering local gitlab-runner to local domain name (gitlab.local).

[Docker cannot resolve dns on private network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400886/docker-cannot-resolve-dns-on-private-network)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. In the end the way I resolved my problem was by registering a different runner that was using shell as an executor.